# Creating half-cylinder walls in a mesh

Tags: bevel

I am new to blender and am having trouble inserting "inward beveling" the walls of my mesh.  I am using 2.91 of Blender.

I have the walls defined - below:

[image: Object without the cylinder templates to cut]

I am using cylinders as templates to create the arc I want in the primary cube. I want to now "cut out" the cylinders and create new walls aligned to the edge of the cylinders where they intersect and bevel inward on the primary cube.  Then I need to add some thickness to those walls.

Here are images from the top of the primary cube and bottom so you can see the vertex.

[image]
[image]

I have tried the boolean modifier but it does not create the inner wall - it just removes from the faces that the cylinder intersects with on the primary cube.  And I am having some issue there where it's not delete anything from the top face (the one without the extrusion).  It might be I need to add a grid fill to create more faces.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please consider seeing a tutorial on Proportional Edit.  With a well populated mesh you can edit with a spherical form.  There are also Boolean operations that can cut subtract one mesh with another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but here is a try, you can use a *Boolean* with a closed shape (put the *Boolean* above the *Mirror* modifier, choose *Solver > Fast*):

[image]

[image]

Then apply the modifiers, delete the bottom face (you'll probably need to clean the topology if you plan to add bevels or use a *Subdivision Surface*, etc), use a *Solidify* modifier to give thickness to your walls (enable the
modifier's *Even Thickness* option):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using [*vertex bevel*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/bevel_vertices.html?#bevel-vertices).

1. Add an edge top and bottom (for now you can <kbd>F</kbd> a temporary face for your object, it will be deleted later)
2. Select the vertices that define the edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> followed by <kbd>P</kbd> to change the profile.

[image]

3. Hide everything except the bevel you just created with <kbd>H</kbd>
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> select and use *[Bridge Edge Loops](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html?#bridge-edge-loops)* to complete the shape on each side

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is pretty cool :). Always wondered what's the use of vertex bevel...

Comment: with vertex bevels you can create round holes, or round corners, etc

Comment: Wow - I never would have figured that one out.  I ended up using Moonboots approach -but will try this one as well.

Comment: Bevel has alot of possibilities using the profile tools (especially new custom profiles). You should accept @moonboots answer if that answer was the best one for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who tries to avoid booleans, as they result in irregular topology most of the time, I would do this operation with **[Proportional Editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?highlight=proportional%20edit)**

Create a few loop cuts, select the edges in the middle, enable proportional editing in *Sphere Falloff* mode. Then scale on one axis only (in this case, to scale only on the $Y$ axis, press <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) and move the mouse. To control the influence of proportional editing (and thus the radius) use the scroll wheel on the mouse.

[image]